# borrar registro que esten dentro de un rango de fechas

Tags: ms-access, delphi

Estoy intentando borrar registros que estén dentro de un rango de fechas 
tengo un pequeño error en mi código:

```
begin 
  query.close;
  query.sql.clear
  query.sql.text := (' delete from tabla where (campo_fecha between :fecha1 and :fecha2);
  query.Parameters.ParamByName('fecha1').DataType := ftDateTime; //aqui tengo el error
  query.Parameters.ParamByName('fecha2').DataType := ftDateTime; // aqui tambien
  query.Parameters.ParamByName('fecha1').Value := FormatDateTime('yyyy/mm/dd',Datetimepicker1.Date);
  query.Parameters.ParamByName('fecha2').Value := FormatDateTime('yyyy/mm/dd',Datetimepicker1.Date);
  query.ExecSQL;
  query.refresh;
end;
```

Trabajo con `Delphi` y `MS ACCESS` y componentes `ADO`.

Este  es mi error: Undeclared identifier: 'ftDateTime'

Comment: Podrias agregar que te dice o que error te da?

Comment: Por favor, indica el mensaje de error exacto que obtienes. Además, el código que publicas no compila.

Comment: Es este es mi error: Undeclared identifier: 'ftDateTime'

Answer (score 2):

El identificador `ftDateTime` pertenece a la enumeración `TFieldTipe`, que está declarada en la unidad `Data.DB` (en versiones antiguas de Delphi simplemente `DB`). Haría falta que declares esta unidad dentro de la causula uses de tu unidad, para que el identificador sea visible, si no tienes ninguna unidad en la clausula uses, quedaría algo similar a:

```
implementation
uses Data.DB;
```

Si ya tienes unidades declaradas, entonces añadela a la lista, separada por una coma, por ejemplo:

```
implementation
uses MiUnidad1, MiUnidad2, Data.DB;
```

Por otro lado, el código que publicas no compila, pero más allá de eso, le encuentro algunos problemas que te voy comentando con cada línea:

```
query.close;
```

Esto tiene mal olor. Puede derivar de una mala práctica, si necesitas iniciar cerrando el objeto `query`, he visto código que tiene un objeto para uso generalizado y en este deja datasets abiertos con cualquier resultado que permanecen así en la memoria y del que el programador pierde control sobre los datos que contienen o para qué se utilizan. Yo sugiero que se cree y se destruya un objeto tipo query cada vez que lo necesitas, esto mantiene el código más limpio y, a medida que la aplicación se hace más compleja, se evitan molestos efectos secundarios y errores difíciles de depurar.

```
  query.sql.clear
  query.sql.text := (' delete from tabla where (campo_fecha between :fecha1 and :fecha2);
```

Le asignas un valor a la propiedad `Text` de `SQL`, que es un `TStrings`. La sentencia anterior que limpia el SQL es, por tanto, superflua. No es que esto tenga un alto costo, pero el hecho de que hayas escrito (o copiado) este código da a entender que no comprendes del todo el funcionamiento de las clases, ni del código que estás escribiendo. Esto también huele mal para mi. Además, en el código que publicas, la cadena de caracteres está mal construida, y por tanto, el compilador dará un error en esta línea.

```
  query.Parameters.ParamByName('fecha1').DataType := ftDateTime; //aqui tengo el error
  query.Parameters.ParamByName('fecha2').DataType := ftDateTime; // aqui tambien
  query.Parameters.ParamByName('fecha1').Value := FormatDateTime('yyyy/mm/dd',Datetimepicker1.Date);
  query.Parameters.ParamByName('fecha2').Value := FormatDateTime('yyyy/mm/dd',Datetimepicker1.Date);
```

Aquí asignas el tipo de dato, como DateTime, y luego asignas una cadena de caracteres a la propiedad. Hay un poco de lo anterior. La propiedad `Value` de los parámetros puede aceptar directamente la fecha o fecha/hora del DateTimePicker y, si hace falta, ajustará de manera automática el tipo del parámetro.

```
  query.ExecSQL;
  query.refresh;
```

Ejecutas el SQL, que contiene una sentencia de borrado, y luego refrescas el objeto Query, que dado que ejecutó un `delete`, no contiene datos, ¿para qué lo refrescas?